# struts jquery plugin - 3.7.1 - popup not opening

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

After upgrading to struts jquery plugin 3.7.1 I am not able to open the pop ups. I am getting the following script error.

```
TypeError: self[o.jqueryaction] is not a function
self[o.jqueryaction]($el, o);
```

Its because of the jquery.struts.js in struts jquery plugin. How can we solve it.. can we override the js file?

Comment: Which version were you using previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by upgrading js to jquery_ui to 1.10.4 and by updating the verions of themes and other css related files to versions of jquery_ui that is 1.10.4.